# Error of foreach command in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a simple picture: lots of nodes and lines connecting them.

So I used `foreach` command to repeat  `-- (P\i)` in `\draw` part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \n in {1,3,2}{
    \node (P\i) at (\i,\n) {P\i};
%   \coordinate (P\i) at (\i,\n);
%   \node at (P\i) {P\i};
}
%\draw (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3);
\draw (P1) foreach \i in {2,3}{ -- (P\i)}; % <--- HERE!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I expected it spells out `(P1) -- (P2) -- (P3)`, but that's not. That command worked like

```
\draw (P1) -- (P2); \draw (P1) -- (P3);
```

I want to draw lines connecting P1, P2, P3, consecutively. If you change `\node` part to `\coordinate` command, it works well. It works like `\draw (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3);`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \n in {1,3,2}{
%   \node (P\i) at (\i,\n) {P\i};
    \coordinate (P\i) at (\i,\n);
    \node at (P\i) {\i};
}
%\draw (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3);
\draw (P1) foreach \i in {2,3}{ -- (P\i)}; % <--- HERE!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does not `foreach` work well for `\node` command?

Comment: It spells out: `\draw (P1) -- (P2); \draw (P1) -- (P3); `.

Comment: @MS-SPO Could you change` \node` part to `\coordinate (P\i) at (\I,\n);`?
Then, it spells out: `\draw (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3);`.

Comment: Try it, but I don’t think so. Coordinates are just nodes with zero dimensions, i.e. a point. If you don’t need to connect hundreds of nodes, it‘s easier and cleaner to just spell it out, like in your commented line. // Keep in mind, paths start with \ and end with ; So your 2nd loop just creates 2 pathes …

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the `remember` option of `foreach`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \n in {1,3,2}{
    \node (P\i) at (\i,\n) {\n};
}

\foreach [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 3)] \i in {1,2,3}{ \draw (P\i)--(P\lasti);};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's better for me to add some examples to the original question. Plz, read again.

Comment: Obviously this is a Tikz bug. You should report it here [pgf/issues](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues)

Comment: I see. I reported it. Thank you.